# Multiple Map values and I want to return those 3 map values in a single object

Tags: java, collections, linkedhashmap

```
Map<String, Integer> map1 = new LinkedHashMap<String,
Map<String, Integer> map2= new LinkedHashMap<String,Integer>();
Map<String, Integer> map3 = new LinkedHashMap<String,Integer>();



//dynamic values

map1.put(value1,value2);
map1.put(value1,value2);
map1.put(value1,value2);


Map.Entry<String,Integer> map1Entry = map1.entrySet().iterator().next();
Map.Entry<String,Integer> map2Entry = map2.entrySet().iterator().next();
Map.Entry<String,Integer> map3Entry = map3.entrySet().iterator().next();


String keyValue1 = map1Entry.getKey();
String keyValue2 = map2Entry.getKey();
String keyValue3 = map3Entry.getKey();
```

I want to return keyValue1, keyValue2, keyValue3. 
Which is the best way to return in a single object?

Comment: Create your own class with 3 ``String`` members and use it as a container for those 3 values.

Comment: Or return a `String[]`.

Comment: Your question title already states your answer: you want to put the keys in a single object.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
 Set<String> TEMP = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[] { keyValue1, keyValue2, keyValue3}));
```

Comment: Tidier to return a `List<String>`? The keys may be the same.

Comment: Keep in mind that you lose the order if you use a `(Hash)Set`